# Route on notification open

Tags: react-native, push-notification

Im using react-native-notifications by wix.
I am having trouble routing to a specific screen when notification is opened. I have tried following this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html. But it is giving me an error.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AppNavigator from './navigation/AppNavigator';
import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo";
import AppNavigator from './navigation/AppNavigator';
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

let _navigator;
function setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef) {
_navigator = navigatorRef;
}

function navigate(routeName, params) {
_navigator.dispatch(
 NavigationActions.navigate({
  routeName,
  params,
  })
 );
 }

export default class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props)

const unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
  console.log("Connection type", state.type);
  console.log("Is connected?", state.isConnected);
  navigate("Rating");
});

Notifications.events().registerNotificationOpened((notification, action, 
completion) => {
  console.log("Notification opened by device user", 
notification.payload);
});

render() {
return (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Root>
       <AppNavigator ref={navigatorRef => {setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef) 
  }}/>
    </Root>
  </Provider>
 );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: First create a variable to hold navigator like this, place it on top of App.js below the imports

```
let _navigator;
function setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef) {
  _navigator = navigatorRef;
}
```

Step 2: Then add a ref property to your AppNavigator like this.

```
ref={navigatorRef => { setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef); }}
```

Step 3: Write the navigate function, which you can call inside the onNotificationRecevied

```
function navigate(routeName, params) {
  _navigator.dispatch(
    NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName,
      params,
    })
  );
}
```

Step 4: Navigate user on receiving notification

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    Notifications.events().registerNotificationOpened((notification, action, completion) => {
        navigate("YOURSCREEN", { params:<date-from-notification-or-any-data> });
    })
}
```

PS: Don't forget to import NavigationActions from 'react-natigation'